# How do I change the timezone on PHP5 for Apache?

Tags: apache2, php

Ok I have a VPS running Ubuntu Server 12.10 32Bit and I need to set the timezone in my PHP.ini file so my PHP Script's time and date features will work (I am trying to setup ModX) I have tried to go to /etc/php5 and change it in different files and it won't work. How do I change PHP's timezone. Also everything in the .ini file has a ; in front of it is that a comment or what? Also I forgot to mention that my webserver in installed via tasksel as LAMP.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your server ?

Comment: I have not restarted my serer but I restarted the Apache service.

Answer (score 5):

find your php.ini and change the value of `date.timezone = Europe/Berlin`

**Edit(Thanks to @awashburn for his comment)**: the php-cli's php.ini file is different then apache2's php.ini file. I suggest symbolic linking one to another to keep them in sync and avoid confusion!

Comment: Which .ini file do I use? Where is the file located for Apache2?

Comment: I use xampp myself. but in your case I think it is in `/etc`, try t o search in your filesystem with `find | grep php.ini`

Comment: Ok please refersh this page in 10 minutes as I am going to try /etc/apache2/php.ini then restart my VPS and see if that works.

Comment: Ok I removed the semicolen and rebooted and it worked fine thanks for both of your help.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a command instead of manually editing the file?

Comment: ***Note:*** the `php-cli`'s `php.ini` file is different then `apache2`'s `php.ini` file. I suggest symbolic linking one to another to keep them in sync and avoid confusion!

Comment: this is the file he meant  /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Answer (score 3):

### 1) Find the right `php.ini` file

#### Apache

Create a file `info.php` with this content:

```
<?php 

phpinfo();
```

Then open the file from a web browser and find the row *Loaded Configuration File*.

#### CLI

Just run this command:

```
$ php --ini
```

### 2) Change the timezone value in the php.ini

Open the right `php.ini` file, search for the `date.timezone =` value (usually under the `[Date]` section), and set:

```
date.timezone = Europe/Berlin
```